# Invalid member declaration in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, oop, declaration, member

I'm new to OOP and Kotlin. For some reason on line 12 of my code, "println(mapOfArithmetic)", I am being given the error that it needs a member declaration. Please help me explain what exactly this is and how I can fix it. Thanks.

---

```kotlin
package entities

class Flashcard2() {
    val mapOfArithmetic = mapOf("1+1" to "=2", "2+2" to "=4",
                                "3+3" to "=6", "4+4" to "=8",
                                "5+5" to "=10", "6+6" to "=12",
                                "7+7" to "=14", "8+8" to "=16",
                                "9+9" to "=18", "10+10" to "=20")

    println(mapOfArithmetic)
}


class FlashcardSet2(var mapOfArithmetic: Map<String, String>) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you have a method call directly inside a class declaration, which is invalid.

What you actually need is to declare a metho within `Flashcard2` so that `println(mapOfArithmetic)` is a valid statement:

```kotlin
class Flashcard2() {
    val mapOfArithmetic = mapOf("1+1" to "=2", "2+2" to "=4",
        "3+3" to "=6", "4+4" to "=8",
        "5+5" to "=10", "6+6" to "=12",
        "7+7" to "=14", "8+8" to "=16",
        "9+9" to "=18", "10+10" to "=20")

    fun print() = println(mapOfArithmetic)
}
```

Comment: Ah, who knew! I though that functions only existed to be called upon and to organize information. I didn't know that the execution of some code actually relied on it being inside a function declaration. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that you can't have the statement `println(mapOfArithmetic)` directly inside a class. Either it must be inside a constructor, or inside a method/function, or being its value assigned to a class variable. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it as the answer ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As João Dias already pointed out, it is not possible to have a function call directly inside your class. So one possible solution is to declare a function and call the `println` inside it.

If you want to have the output on every instantiation of your class `Flashcard2`, it would instead be better to put the call inside a constructor:

```
class Flashcard2 {
    val mapOfArithmetic = mapOf("1+1" to "=2", "2+2" to "=4",
                                "3+3" to "=6", "4+4" to "=8",
                                "5+5" to "=10", "6+6" to "=12",
                                "7+7" to "=14", "8+8" to "=16",
                                "9+9" to "=18", "10+10" to "=20")

    constructor() {
        println(mapOfArithmetic)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can call it inside an `init` block:

```
class Flashcard2() {
    val mapOfArithmetic = mapOf("1+1" to "=2", "2+2" to "=4",
                                "3+3" to "=6", "4+4" to "=8",
                                "5+5" to "=10", "6+6" to "=12",
                                "7+7" to "=14", "8+8" to "=16",
                                "9+9" to "=18", "10+10" to "=20")

    init {
        println(mapOfArithmetic)
    }
}
```

This way you do not need the definition of a function, and the expression is called on any instantiation of the class.